# Directory structure in MVC: Do strategy objects go in models folder?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Which folder should I put strategy objects, or any objects that are not domain models?  I'm using Zend Framework, if that matters.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two pretty standard options:

1. Place this code into the `library` folder. Typically a file `library/App/SomePackage/SomeClass.php` wouldcontain the class `App_SomePackage_SomeClass`. Just add the line `autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"` into your `configs/application.ini` file.
2. Create a new folder inside your `application` folder and configure a `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` (or its extended class `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`) with appropriate appnamespaces, paths, and prefixes.

Using this second approach could go something like this:

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Application_',
        'basePath'  =>  APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));
    $resourceLoader->addResourceType('strategy', 'strategies', 'Strategy');
}
```

Then a class named `Application_Strategy_SomeClass` would reside in the file `application/strategies/SomeClass.php`.

Noe that using `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` - instead of the more generic parent `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` - will give you a standard set of autoloader mappings for models, forms, services, view helpers, etc.

Comment: Gotcha, the second approach is what I was looking for, thx a lot for taking the time out to reply, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the recommended folder structure laid out [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html) in the **Zend Programmer's Reference Guide** and place them into the modules folder.